# What does "tum of the ear" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What the meaning of this phrase "tum of the ear" in this sentence?
India had developed by the tum of the ear into a major exporter.

Comment: It's nonsense. Could be a mistranscription of "turn of the year".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about some kind of typo

Comment: Link to the original and quote the context. As is, it sounds like nonsense to me, but could be a typo. Maybe 'turn of the ear' is a common phrase in Indian English?

Comment: Obviously, "Tum of the ear" is a medication you take for an earache.

Answer (score 3):

It's a typo from a (non-Anglophone) [language learning source...](http://behseen.ir/groups/TOEFL%20Preparation%20-%20ApplyAbroad/45/2447)

[image]

...but note that *idiomatically*, native speakers would almost never put the adverbial clause ***by the turn of the year<sup>1</sup>*** between the main verb *(**had developed**)* and its preposition-based complement *(**into a major exporter**)*. They'd either put it before or after the primary statement...

> ***By the turn of the year*** India had developed into a major exporter
>    OR
>    *India had developed into a major exporter **by the turn of the year***

---

<sup>1</sup> The intended word could have been ***era*** or ***year*** - but that not really important, since the sentence didn't (and was never *likely* to) come from a native speaker in the first place. And *idiomatically*, this particular turn of phrase normally only occurs as [*by the turn of the **century***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20turn%20of%20the%20year%2Cthe%20turn%20of%20the%20century&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20turn%20of%20the%20year%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20turn%20of%20the%20century%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Native speakers might actually have done that a hundred years ago; this rule "don't put anything between the verb and the object if you can help it" is new—this kind of phrasing is relatively frequent in 19th century novels. And [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=took+immediately+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctook%20immediately%20the%3B%2Cc0) is evidence for this from Ngrams.

Comment: That last Ngram is a little suspect, because *immediately took the* also declined significantly in usage during this period. [Here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=immediately+became+the%2Cbecame+immediately+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimmediately%20became%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbecame%20immediately%20the%3B%2Cc0) is a better example.

Comment: @Peter: That's a *very* interesting chart though! But if I switch *took immediately **the*** to *took immediately **to*** (so the "complement / object" is a ***preposition-based*** element), that dramatic usage shift seems far less pronounced. Which I'm cautiously interpreting as implying the explicitly preposition-based versions were never that popular anyway, so they couldn't fall so far out of favour! :)

Comment: Just as an aside, I investigated this after I had binged on 1920s and 1930s mystery novels, and had noticed that this kind of construction was fairly common in them (I forget which authors used it, though).

Comment: I often think that Victorian (and earlier) writers habitually used "slightly unusual" phrasing (and in particular, "creative" positioning of adverbial elements) to give their readers something to chew on / get their teeth into. Which we almost *expect* even today in some "poetry" contexts - but when it comes to "prose", we'd rather see everything more "standardised", with less circumlocution and "creative" sequences.

Comment: (The idea presumably being that if you have to pay attention to slightly convoluted *syntax*, maybe this will also encourage you to pay more attention to ***everything*** about the text! :)